# Group items in array based on array value HTML

Tags: html

I have this array and would like to categorize the `name` value, based on the `group` value in my HTML file.

This is a snippet of relevant parts from my .TS file where I have the arrays.

```
export let Students = [
    {
     'name': 'Alex',
     'age': '14',
     'group': 'Regular',
    },
```

I have tried to remove the  tags, but that does not give the desired result. I feel like that there is a much more efficient and simple way of going about this.

Answer (score 2):

You could group your first array by group, and then iterate over both array. :

```
 //so we can access "this" in the callback. 
 let parent = this;
 this.Students.forEach((item) => {
    if(!parent.groupedStudents.hasOwnProperty(item.group)) {
        parent.groupedStudents[item.group] = { title: item.group, students: []}
    }
    parent.groupedStudents[item.group].students.push(item);
});
// we cannot iterate over object in ngFor, so we use only the values.
this.groupedStudents = Object.values(this.groupedStudents);
```

And in your template

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let item of main.groupedStudents">
    <ion-list-header>
        <ion-label>{{item.title}}</ion-label>
    </ion-list-header>

    <ion-label *ngFor="let student of item.students>{{student.name}}</ion-label>
</ng-container>
```

I have made a basic angular app using this [here](https://jsfiddle.net/ya6fsjvo/)

Comment: at what line and what's the code associated with that line in your TS file ?

Comment: Check the way you are accessing the  `Students` variable. maybe you don't need the `this`. @ellierad

Comment: You probably have to remove the `this` aswell. I'm using my code in a Angular type of way, that's why i'm using `this`.

Comment: Also, `groupedStudents` is suposed to be a class variable in my angular.